# How to Import/Export Group field in Contacts via VCF?

Tags: contacts

OS: 2.1
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S (Vibrant)

When exporting or emailing a VCF file from the Contacts app, the Group data (e.g. Family, Friends) does not get exported.  Similarly, the CATEGORIES property is ignored when importing a VCF file.  Does anyone know how to get this data into/out of the Contacts app via VCF?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this on the web inside of gmail, right?

I didn't see the groups included in the VCF file either.  But they do seem to be included if you export it as a CSV.  Is it possible that you can use the CSV instead?

Comment: No, this is within the phone contact manager itself.  My contacts do not sync with my Google contacts.  Not sure why, and I'm not sure I want them too, anyway.