# Importing group associations _only_

Tags: contacts, import, contact-groups

(Following question to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231577/142320))
Suppose I have an .xls or .csv file with associations of contact names to groups (or firstname, middlename, lastname to group).

I want to import these associations  - applied to existing contacts; I don't want to create new skeleton contacts based on these associations. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The **[SA Contacts Lite](http://samapp.com/excelcontacts)** application, which can import and export contacts more generally, can be used specifically for this purpose:

1. Download & install SA Contacts Lite application; it is available on places where you don't need an account, e.g. [via APKPure.com](https://apkpure.com/sa-contacts-lite/com.samapp.excelcontacts.excelcontactslite).
2. Remove all columns from your the file except for the names/name components and the group associations (i.e. remove all the columns you don't want to import)
3. Save the whittled-down file to the root of your phone's storage hierarchy
4. In SA Contacts Lite, click <kbd>Import</kbd>.
5. Choose `SD Card` as the location in which to search for the import file (or someplace else, if you put your file on Box/DropBox/Google Drive and have that configured in SA Contacts Lite; I didn't do this); press <kbd>Next</kbd>.
6. Select the `.xls` file in the dialog which comes up; press <kbd>Next</kbd>.

That's basically it. Your existing contacts will now also have the group associations.

Notes:

- I've tried this with an Excel file: `.xls`, not `.xlsx`. Not sure if it also works with `.csv` files.